# How can I generate 3d integer coordinates in order of distance from an origin

Tags: coordinates, generator

I want to generate a sequence of coordinates in order of distance from the origin. The sequence will obviously be infinite so just generating them all and sorting by distance will not work for me.

For those points that are the same distance I don't care about the order.

For example, here's some points, with their distance from the origin up to two steps away.

```
# d² = 0
(0,0,0)
# d² = 1
(0,0,-1)
(0,-1,0)
(-1,0,0)
(1,0,0)
(0,1,0)
(0,0,1)
# d² = 2
(0,-1,-1)
(-1,0,-1)
(1,0,-1)
(0,1,-1)
(-1,-1,0)
(1,-1,0)
(-1,1,0)
(1,1,0)
(0,-1,1)
(-1,0,1)
(1,0,1)
(0,1,1)
# d² = 3
(-1,-1,-1)
(1,-1,-1)
(-1,1,-1)
(1,1,-1)
(-1,-1,1)
(1,-1,1)
(-1,1,1)
(1,1,1)
# d² = 4
(0,0,-2)
(0,-2,0)
(-2,0,0)
(2,0,0)
(0,2,0)
(0,0,2)
# d² = 5
(0,-1,-2)
(-1,0,-2)
(1,0,-2)
(0,1,-2)
(0,-2,-1)
(-2,0,-1)
(2,0,-1)
(0,2,-1)
(-1,-2,0)
(1,-2,0)
(-2,-1,0)
(2,-1,0)
(-2,1,0)
(2,1,0)
(-1,2,0)
(1,2,0)
(0,-2,1)
(-2,0,1)
(2,0,1)
(0,2,1)
(0,-1,2)
(-1,0,2)
(1,0,2)
(0,1,2)
# d² = 6
(-1,-1,-2)
(1,-1,-2)
(-1,1,-2)
(1,1,-2)
(-1,-2,-1)
(1,-2,-1)
(-2,-1,-1)
(2,-1,-1)
(-2,1,-1)
(2,1,-1)
(-1,2,-1)
(1,2,-1)
(-1,-2,1)
(1,-2,1)
(-2,-1,1)
(2,-1,1)
(-2,1,1)
(2,1,1)
(-1,2,1)
(1,2,1)
(-1,-1,2)
(1,-1,2)
(-1,1,2)
(1,1,2)
# d² = 8
(0,-2,-2)
(-2,0,-2)
(2,0,-2)
(0,2,-2)
(-2,-2,0)
(2,-2,0)
(-2,2,0)
(2,2,0)
(0,-2,2)
(-2,0,2)
(2,0,2)
(0,2,2)
# d² = 9
(-1,-2,-2)
(1,-2,-2)
(-2,-1,-2)
(2,-1,-2)
(-2,1,-2)
(2,1,-2)
(-1,2,-2)
(1,2,-2)
(-2,-2,-1)
(2,-2,-1)
(-2,2,-1)
(2,2,-1)
(-2,-2,1)
(2,-2,1)
(-2,2,1)
(2,2,1)
(-1,-2,2)
(1,-2,2)
(-2,-1,2)
(2,-1,2)
(-2,1,2)
(2,1,2)
(-1,2,2)
(1,2,2)
# d² = 12
(-2,-2,-2)
(2,-2,-2)
(-2,2,-2)
(2,2,-2)
(-2,-2,2)
(2,-2,2)
(-2,2,2)
(2,2,2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from a solution aaa, then aab, then abc, you can retrieve all other "permutations" like aba, baa, -a-a-b, and so on. So you can keep a < b < c, positive numbers.

Geometrically : one eighth triangle on a globe. For a circle x²+y² one would iterate in a quarter over x and let y be retrieved from r² - x². Happens here to given an  `a`.

Unfortunately the coding is too much to me for answering on a sunny Sunday.
(= hard enough).
Schematically in pseudo-code:

```
int distance = -1;
int a;
int b;
int c;
PermutationIterator perm = ...

Point next() {
    if (perm.atEnd()) { // Initially true.
        perm.nextDistance();
        ++distance;
        a = distance;
        b = a;
        c = a;
        // Will return Point(a, a, a);
    }
    return perm.nextPerm();
}
```